# Python script on heroku stops after a while

Tags: python, bash, heroku

I'm running scrip with heroku bash. It stops after a different time from the start. The message in bash says:
Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
Process exited with status 129

Can't find any related info about this exitcode. What does it mean?

I suppose that bash is terminated on heroku by some input timeout and script which was running on that dyno was also terminated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide more information? What does the script do, and how are you running it? The [ask] page has some good tips on asking questions effectively.